# Wordress index page redirects to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have change the directory of my wordpress project from

/root/demoweb/web to /root

but index page still redirecting to old one.

I have changed the .htaccess configurations and settings/ general admin settings also.

what should i do ?

Comment: Check database also and search there for occurrence of any old URL. Also check your wp-config.php for any hard-coded URL.

Comment: check the database for home url and site url entries - these might not have changed

Comment: after that - regenerate permalinks as well

Answer (score 2):

This is the queries I usually perform (of course replace the value **old_url** and **new_url** by yours):

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_url', 'new_url') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'old_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'old_url', 'new_url');
```

- Then checking if there is a redirect in .htaccess.
- Then accessing the admin URL by going to my **new_url/wp-admin/** and regenerating the permalinks (Settings > Permalinks, and click save changes).
- Last one: clean your cache if you got a caching plugin or server-module.

Answer (score 0):

Database needs changes,follow the steps

1. first yake full backup before.
2. open your database, export
   that.
3. open with an editor application.
4. find and replace all
   of: find all: "old_url" to replace all: "new_url"
5. save this file.
6. import the database.

enjoy the website :-)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What if the database changes in between (due to new comments, or new posts)?

Answer (score -1):

you have to change root path in your apache server file which is apache.conf .

Comment: To change Apache's root directory, run: cd /etc/apache2/sites-available.
Then open the 000-default.conf file using the command: nano 000-default.conf.
Edit the DocumentRoot option: DocumentRoot /root